# Counting colour and grayscale print jobs

Tags: winapi, printing, spool

I'm writing a small application that's supposed to count the number of colour and grayscale jobs going to local printers.

It's meant to cross reference with what the printer records. If there is any non-grayscale elements on the job, the printer records a colour job.

At the moment I'm using the EnumJobs call but I can't get any colour info on it. I'm starting to think I'll have to read the spl files that are spooling to scan it for a colour palette...

I've tried a few print auditing applications and some of them are able to do it.

Any pointers will be much appreciated!

Comment: Just FYI, I ended up reading the spool files for colour indicators. This works surprisingly well, except there are a few printer drivers that do not create compatible spool files.